# Null Values in Subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have  subquery where CompletedDate have Null Values i need to add tht null values my Output with not null values .

```
       select * from Crew c
 where 

 a.CrewDate > '2016/12/22 00:00:00'  
   and ActionTypeID = 20
 ---  and objectid = 73658
  AND CrewDate IN (SELECT MAX(CrewDate) FROM Crew cc WHERE c.ObjectID = 
  cc.ObjectID
   AND cc.crewTypeID = 20
    )
 **AND A.CompletedDate IN  (SELECT MAX(CompletedDate)   FROM crew cc WHERE 
 c.ObjectID = cc.ObjectID  
AND AA.ActionTypeID = 20**
 )
   order by ObjectID

oBJECTid     CompletedDate               Createddate
1445209     2017-01-04 09:36:30          2016-12-22 00:00:03
3145514     2017-01-30 15:43:02          2016-12-22 00:00:03
2778154     NULL                         2016-12-22 00:00:03
3025853     2017-01-30 15:43:02          2016-12-22 00:00:03
2342785     2017-03-03 12:02:17          2016-12-22 00:00:03
3113524     NULL                         2016-12-22 08:04:58
3198917     2017-08-16 07:38:29          2016-12-22 08:06:08
1245218     NULL                         2016-12-22 08:12:20
3433585     NULL                         2016-12-22 08:14:35
```

at the moment my query taking out Null values but i need null values in output

Comment: show some data and expected output

Comment: You mean **AND A.CompletedDate IN  (SELECT MAX(CompletedDate)   FROM crew cc WHERE 
 c.ObjectID = cc.ObjectID  
AND AA.ActionTypeID = 20**
 ) OR  A.CompletedDate  is null ?? Or it could be null but AA.ActionTypeID = 20 as well? Explain it better please

Comment: @MiloBellano in subquery where complteddate is null or not null

Comment: @StevenBENET Added

Comment: try this as subquery (SELECT case when CompletedDate is not null then MAX(CompletedDate) else null end as CompletedDate)

Comment: @MiloBellano getting error Column 'Crew.CompletedDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your issue, then you need to use [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) sub-query instead of `IN` sub-query

Please review next SQL code:

```
SELECT
    c.ObjectID,
    cc.MaxCrewDate,
    cd.MaxCompletedDate
FROM Crew c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        cc.ObjectID
        MAX(cc.CrewDate) AS MaxCrewDate
    FROM Crew cc
    WHERE cc.crewTypeID = 20
    GROUP BY cc.ObjectID
) AS cc ON cc.ObjectID = c.ObjectID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        cd.ObjectID,
        MAX(CompletedDate) AS MaxCompletedDate
    FROM Crew cd
    WHERE cd.ActionTypeID = 20
    GROUP BY cd.ObjectID
) AS cd ON cd.ObjectID = c.ObjectID
```

Comment: Its okay if objectid have duplicate thats why i was sing IN clause so its give me latest entry by datetime